# Manipulate a list based on a given element of that list (the second element in this case)

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the following list:

```
list={{{0.01, 87., 0.}, {0.03, 87., 0.18353}, {0.1, 87., 0.494987}, {0.3, 
   87., 0.899803}, {1., 87., 1.08076}, {3., 87., 1.10593}, {10., 87., 
   1.04781}, {10., 87., 1.02449}, {10., 87., 0.964193}, {30., 87., 
   1.0602}, {30., 87., 1.04075}, {30., 87., 1.05987}, {100., 87., 
   1.14661}, {100., 87., 1.00639}, {100., 87., 1.09384}, {300., 87., 
   1.067}, {300., 87., 1.15047}, {300., 87., 1.10715}, {1000., 87., 
   1.05152}, {1000., 87., 1.06942}, {1000., 87., 1.17143}, {3000., 
   87., 1.12162}, {10000., 87., 1.13136}}, {{0.01, 85., 0.}, {0.03, 
   85., 0.}, {0.1, 85., 0.443129}, {0.3, 85., 0.527854}, {1., 85., 
   0.974597}, {3., 85., 1.08727}, {10., 85., 1.09881}, {10., 85., 
   0.991704}, {10., 85., 1.09402}, {30., 85., 1.09783}, {30., 85., 
   1.14965}, {30., 85., 1.13956}, {100., 85., 0.987854}, {100., 85., 
   1.13173}, {100., 85., 1.23912}, {300., 85., 1.13003}, {300., 85., 
   1.09923}, {300., 85., 1.11004}, {1000., 85., 1.04733}, {1000., 85.,
    1.08491}, {1000., 85., 1.11656}, {3000., 85., 1.06112}, {10000., 
   85., 1.05261}}, {{0.01, 80., 0.}, {0.03, 80., 0.}, {0.1, 80., 
   0.215019}, {0.3, 80., 0.702618}, {1., 80., 1.27573}, {3., 80., 
   1.02397}, {10., 80., 1.1375}, {10., 80., 1.14245}, {10., 80., 
   0.945541}, {30., 80., 1.33324}, {30., 80., 1.07789}, {30., 80., 
   1.12324}, {100., 80., 1.14999}, {100., 80., 0.985026}, {100., 80., 
   1.1228}, {300., 80., 1.25291}, {300., 80., 1.29771}, {300., 80., 
   1.40179}, {1000., 80., 1.26045}, {1000., 80., 1.17871}, {1000., 
   80., 1.32166}, {3000., 80., 1.27041}, {10000., 80., 
   1.23387}}, {{0.01, 75., 0.}, {0.03, 75., 0.}, {0.1, 75., 
   0.0959691}, {0.3, 75., 0.37954}, {1., 75., 0.678807}, {3., 75., 
   0.90385}, {10., 75., 0.965262}, {10., 75., 1.01025}, {10., 75., 
   1.01675}, {30., 75., 1.04836}, {30., 75., 1.11345}, {30., 75., 
   1.09146}, {100., 75., 1.16961}, {100., 75., 1.19018}, {100., 75., 
   1.16968}, {300., 75., 1.20834}, {300., 75., 1.22955}, {300., 75., 
   1.19569}, {1000., 75., 1.25479}, {1000., 75., 1.32295}, {1000., 
   75., 1.22151}, {3000., 75., 1.28794}, {10000., 75., 
   1.25897}}, {{0.01, 70., 0.}, {0.03, 70., 0.}, {0.1, 70., 
   0.12702}, {0.3, 70., 0.284862}, {1., 70., 0.330209}, {3., 70., 
   0.490592}, {10., 70., 0.864811}, {30., 70., 0.951112}, {100., 70., 
   0.924481}, {300., 70., 1.02702}, {1000., 70., 1.12306}, {3000., 
   70., 1.061}, {10000., 70., 1.08021}}, {{0.01, 65., 0.}, {0.03, 65.,
    0.}, {0.1, 65., 0.}, {0.3, 65., 0.}, {1., 65., 0.}, {3., 65., 
   0.0267647}, {10., 65., 0.377013}, {30., 65., 0.616391}, {100., 65.,
    0.876983}, {300., 65., 1.02765}, {1000., 65., 1.13803}, {3000., 
   65., 1.13322}, {10000., 65., 1.21018}}, {{0.01, 60., 0.}, {0.03, 
   60., 0.}, {0.1, 60., 0.}, {0.3, 60., 0.}, {1., 60., 0.}, {3., 60., 
   0.}, {10., 60., 0.}, {10., 60., 0.}, {10., 60., 0.}, {30., 60., 
   0.294614}, {100., 60., 0.430481}, {300., 60., 0.635893}, {1000., 
   60., 0.88309}, {3000., 60., 1.18007}, {10000., 60., 
   1.28467}}, {{0.01, 55., 0.}, {0.03, 55., 0.}, {0.1, 55., 0.}, {0.3,
    55., 0.}, {1., 55., 0.}, {3., 55., 0.}, {10., 55., 0.}, {10., 55.,
    0.}, {10., 55., 0.}, {30., 55., 0.}, {30., 55., 0.}, {30., 55., 
   0.}, {100., 55., 0.}, {100., 55., 0.}, {100., 55., 0.}, {300., 55.,
    0.0721335}, {1000., 55., 0.214175}, {3000., 55., 
   0.748622}, {10000., 55., 1.05191}}}
```

how can I get the same list but ignoring the sublists based on the second value. For example, how can I get the same list avoiding numbers lower than 75 based on the second value (e.g.{firt  value,second value,third value},{firt  value,second value,third value}.....)as to get:

```
list={{{0.01, 87., 0.}, {0.03, 87., 0.18353}, {0.1, 87., 0.494987}, {0.3, 
   87., 0.899803}, {1., 87., 1.08076}, {3., 87., 1.10593}, {10., 87., 
   1.04781}, {10., 87., 1.02449}, {10., 87., 0.964193}, {30., 87., 
   1.0602}, {30., 87., 1.04075}, {30., 87., 1.05987}, {100., 87., 
   1.14661}, {100., 87., 1.00639}, {100., 87., 1.09384}, {300., 87., 
   1.067}, {300., 87., 1.15047}, {300., 87., 1.10715}, {1000., 87., 
   1.05152}, {1000., 87., 1.06942}, {1000., 87., 1.17143}, {3000., 
   87., 1.12162}, {10000., 87., 1.13136}}, {{0.01, 85., 0.}, {0.03, 
   85., 0.}, {0.1, 85., 0.443129}, {0.3, 85., 0.527854}, {1., 85., 
   0.974597}, {3., 85., 1.08727}, {10., 85., 1.09881}, {10., 85., 
   0.991704}, {10., 85., 1.09402}, {30., 85., 1.09783}, {30., 85., 
   1.14965}, {30., 85., 1.13956}, {100., 85., 0.987854}, {100., 85., 
   1.13173}, {100., 85., 1.23912}, {300., 85., 1.13003}, {300., 85., 
   1.09923}, {300., 85., 1.11004}, {1000., 85., 1.04733}, {1000., 85.,
    1.08491}, {1000., 85., 1.11656}, {3000., 85., 1.06112}, {10000., 
   85., 1.05261}}, {{0.01, 80., 0.}, {0.03, 80., 0.}, {0.1, 80., 
   0.215019}, {0.3, 80., 0.702618}, {1., 80., 1.27573}, {3., 80., 
   1.02397}, {10., 80., 1.1375}, {10., 80., 1.14245}, {10., 80., 
   0.945541}, {30., 80., 1.33324}, {30., 80., 1.07789}, {30., 80., 
   1.12324}, {100., 80., 1.14999}, {100., 80., 0.985026}, {100., 80., 
   1.1228}, {300., 80., 1.25291}, {300., 80., 1.29771}, {300., 80., 
   1.40179}, {1000., 80., 1.26045}, {1000., 80., 1.17871}, {1000., 
   80., 1.32166}, {3000., 80., 1.27041}, {10000., 80., 
   1.23387}}, {{0.01, 75., 0.}, {0.03, 75., 0.}, {0.1, 75., 
   0.0959691}, {0.3, 75., 0.37954}, {1., 75., 0.678807}, {3., 75., 
   0.90385}, {10., 75., 0.965262}, {10., 75., 1.01025}, {10., 75., 
   1.01675}, {30., 75., 1.04836}, {30., 75., 1.11345}, {30., 75., 
   1.09146}, {100., 75., 1.16961}, {100., 75., 1.19018}, {100., 75., 
   1.16968}, {300., 75., 1.20834}, {300., 75., 1.22955}, {300., 75., 
   1.19569}, {1000., 75., 1.25479}, {1000., 75., 1.32295}, {1000., 
   75., 1.22151}, {3000., 75., 1.28794}, {10000., 75., 
   1.25897}}}
```

In the same way how can I get the same list based on the second when the second value is between 75 and 55.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[{}] @ Map[Select[#[[2]] >= 75 &]] @ list
```

[image]

```
DeleteCases[{}] @ Map[Select[55 <= #[[2]] < 75 &]] @ list
```

[image]

Comment: kglr Thank you!. It works but there is something extra that is generated at the end of the list like `{}`.how can I avoid the `{}` that are generated at the end of the code?

Comment: @John, please see the updated version.

Comment: This works great! Thank you !!!